# Dual-Boot Windows 8.1 and BackTrack 5 R3 ISO with EasyBCD 2.2

Tags: terminal, windows-8.1, backtrack, easybcd, grub4dos

I have a PC running Windows 8.1 (32-bit) and the BackTrack 5 R3 (KDE). I've installed Backtrack and it appeared on the boot menu, but whenever I select it, it always takes me to a terminal called Grub4dos, and I don't know how to use it.

I don't know how to use this terminal and I need help. Any answers?

Comment: youtube has a bunch of tutorials. They'll probably have this as well. Just to throw this out for you, Backtrack 5 R3 is no longer being supported, they've moved to a new forensics flavor: Kali. more here: http://www.kali.org/ There's a big community you might be able to get more support there.